# Why are my images resizing unpredictably?

Tags: html, css

So i am working on a photo portfolio that has a side scrolling main content element. I have been playing around with all of the previous responsive tricks I have found to get the images to scale properly as the browsers height changes.

Alas, as I scale the browser vertically, the images break aspect ratio and distort. The thing that I am finding confusing about this is, if I start with a constricted height browser, the images load small to match and will scale up proportionally, then scale down accordingly. However when the browser starts large the scale down breaks the ratio. I am assuming this is something to do with the way I have constructed the #scroller container. But I am none the wiser

I have tried putting the images directly into the #scroller. I added children divs and then put the imgs, into them, i even tried a table.

I really don't get it.

```
#scroller { 
    position:absolute;
    top:8%;
    height:80%; 
    width:auto;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    z-index:1;
    padding:10px 0 10px 252px;
    white-space:nowrap;
}


#scroller img {
    height:100%;
    display:inline-block;
    width:auto;

}
```

I have loaded it into a JsFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/Za544/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `max-height:100%;` instead of just `height:100%;`

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/Za544/1/

```
#scroller img { 

    max-height:100%; 
    display:inline-block;
    width:auto;
    white-space:normal;

    }
```

Comment: I tried that, but not all of the images are the same height on load and they still get crushed vertically at some point.

Comment: you can use both `height: 100%` and `max-height: 100%`

Comment: Tried that, still breaking ratio on resize

Comment: It's difficult to debug as within the fiddle, using `max-height: 100%;`, it works perfectly without fault, every time.

Comment: In the real browser it is still not working. Going to try and write a Js solution instead because i fear that i may struggle to get this working with just vanilla CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly I found that if I set the child image position attribute to absolute or fixed they scaled correctly. Although that broke the positioning. I also found that floating the images left agains each other works. I should then be able to clear the float.

Thanks for your answers. Still puzzled by the strange functionality i was getting only on scale down and not scale up.